# React Native - Getting all data from ListView DataSource

Tags: listview, react-native, datasource

There's currently no way to get all of the `dataSource`'s data with a single function call.

The only way to get all of its data is to loop through each row index and section index and calling `getRowData(sectionIndex, rowIndex)`.

Right now, I'm getting all of its data by accessing its `_dataBlob` but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Is there a function out there that allows me to get all of `dataSource`'s data?